# Avoid redirect page in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-admin

this is my e-commerce portfolio page with password authentication.

Here the image is of two types

1. blur and  2. original

[main portfolio blur images (before entering password)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDJM.png)

If the password is correct, the httpresponse returns the original image.

you can see url of portfolio website images
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gS1t.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk85f.png).

**in that just want:**

**from:** /trail/1234

**to:** /trail#1234

**means don't want to redirect page**

Answer (score 0):

You could just render a different page depending on if the login is valid or not. (I'm not sure if you are doing a custom login View or using the default)

```py
if login.valid(): # this line is prob not correct

    # redirect to correct page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginhome'))
else:
    # redirect to the same page but with a location hash
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginpage')+"#invalid")
```

Also you could just, or as well, add a `@login_required` decorator to the other page. Even if they get redirected to that page, they'll be bounced back to the login.